# Cast table to a struct

Tags: c

I want cast a table of int to a struct

```
int tab[10];
struct
{
 int a;
 int b;
}maStruct;
int main()
{
 ((maStruct*)(tab))->b=(int)2;
}
```

this didn't compile what's wrong in your opinion???

Comment: My opinion that you should read the compiler error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define your `maStruct` type properly and also add return value to your function. This code compiles:

```
int tab[10];
typedef struct maStruct
{
 int a;
 int b;
} maStruct;
int main()
{
 ((maStruct*)(tab))->b=(int)2;
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`maStruct` is a variable name, not a type. Did you mean

```
typedef struct 
{
    int a;
    int b;
} maStruct;
```

instead?